# how to make queue.get return as fast as possible

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I have a following code snippet, using the multiprocessing module:

```
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

q = Queue()

def feeder():
    x=0
    while True:
       q.put(x)
       time.sleep(1)
       x+=1

p=Process(target=feeder).start()

while True:
    print q.get()
```

Now `q.get` prints every second, as the new data arrives in the queue. I'd like the `q.get` returns (i.e. by raising an error or by returning None, or by other method) as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read [the documentation for `.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get)?

```
while True:
    try:
        print q.get(block=False)  # or q.get_nowait()
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
```

Comment: Yes, I don't know how could I missed it. I think I focused on the examples. Thanks